# Angular UI-router switch between multi views to single view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an app which has three views (`ui-view` using Angular ui-router):
*header*, *sidebar* and *content*.

my **index.html** looks like this: (I omitted the actual classes for clearness)

```
<body>
    <div ui-view="header" class="..."></div>

    <div class="page-container">
        <div ui-view="sidebar" class="..."></div>
            <div class="page-content"> 
                <div ui-view="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This pattern works well with pages that have the *header* and *sidebar*.
But I have some pages that I don't want to display the *header* and *sidebar*, for example a login page that should fit on all page.
For this kind of pages I need something like:

`ui-view` which should look like this:

```
<body>
     <div ui-view="content"></div>
</body>
```

So it won't be nested and under the other views `<div>`'s and affected by their classes.

I have some solutions in mind, but none of them gave me a good enough UX.
I tried adding `<ng hide>` to the *header* and *sidebar* depending on the state. It worked but there was annoying flickering (that I couldn't eliminate with `ng-cloak` for some reason..)

To make things more clear, here is an example of two states , one is "one pager" and the other is full page with header and sidebar:

```
.state('Login', {
  url: '/login',
  views: {                  
    'content': {
      templateUrl: './../templates/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('Users', {
  url: '/users',
  views: {    
    'header': {
      templateUrl: './../templates/header.html',
      controller: 'HeaderCtrl'
    },    
    'sidebar': {
      templateUrl: './../templates/sidebar.html',
      controller: 'SidebarCtrl'
    },                            
    'content': {
      templateUrl: './../templates/users.html',
      controller: 'UsersCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

I also think using nested views, but not sure whether this is the right approach.

Comment: *My approach is to always have super parent - per states family. E.g. root (for usual) rootDoc (documentation state family) rootSec (login)... These root states do contain main templates... and that means, that some of them does not have to keep header or sidebar...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try using nested states, ie:

```
.state('app', {
  url: '/app',
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: './../templates/treeViewTemplate.html'
})
.state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  templateUrl: './../templates/login.html',
  controller: 'LoginCtrl'
})
.state('app.users', {
  url: '/users',
  views: {    
    'header': {
      templateUrl: './../templates/header.html',
      controller: 'HeaderCtrl'
    },    
    'sidebar': {
      templateUrl: './../templates/sidebar.html',
      controller: 'SidebarCtrl'
    },                            
    'content': {
      templateUrl: './../templates/users.html',
      controller: 'UsersCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

In your root abstract state you define a template for 3 view-layout. `login` state will instead take whole display.